# c realloc - memory not allocated as i set it

Tags: c, allocation, realloc

i build a function that will delete a word in text that i wrote, the function works,

but from some reason the memory is more then i allocated so after i finish it print the new string without the word but with symbols and gibberish.

please help me understand why and how could i fix it, thank you.

when i debugged the memory change soon as i used this :

```
newStr[k] = str[i];



char * newText(char * word, char *str)
{
 int count = 0, indexS = -1,indexE = -1;
 char *newStr = (char*)calloc(1,sizeof(char));
 int w = 0, k = 0,i,i2;
 if(strlen(word) > strlen(str))
     printf("Error: the word dosent exist");
 else
 {
     for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
     {
         if (str[i] != word[w])
         {
             newStr[k] = str[i];
             k++;
             newStr = realloc(newStr, k + 1);
         }
         else
         {
             i2 = i;
             while (str[i2] != ' ' && str[i2] != '\0')
             {
                 if (str[i2] == word[w])
                 {
                     count++;
                     w++;
                     i2++;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     count = -1;
                     break;
                 }

             }
             if (strlen(word) == count)
             {
                 i = i2;
                 if (str != '\0') i++; // space
             }
             else
             {
                 newStr[k] = str[i];
                 k++;
                 newStr = realloc(newStr, k + 1);
             }
             count = 0;
             w = 0;
         }
    }
 }
 str[k] = '\0';
 return newStr;
}
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: You forgot to null-terminate newStr.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) always check (!=NULL) to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned type is `void*` so can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  3) when calling `realloc()`, do not assign the returned pointer to the target variable until after checking (!=NULL) to assure the operation was successful.  Otherwise, the original pointer is lost, resulting in a memory leak

Comment: regarding: `if (str[i] != word[w])`  This is not comparing correctly.  Suggest using the function: `strstr()` to find any matching word in the string.  Suggest first action to be copy the whole string into newstr by an initial malloc() the `strcpy()`, the use `strstr()` to find any char sequence matching `word` and if found, move the chars (after the end of `word`) to overlay where the `word` was found. A call to `memmove()` with appropriate parameters would make that simple.  Be sure to always NUL terminate the `newstr` contents

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings. ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are appending `'\0'` character to the wrong string at the end before you return:

```
str[k] = '\0';
```

make it:

```
newStr[k] = '\0';
```